# Как вычесть два объекта типа DateInterval в PHP?

Tags: php, datetime

Всем привет!
Создаю тайм трекер на PHP, и приходится много работать со временем и датами. Столкнулся с проблемой с вычитанием дат, если отнимать два объекта **DateTime** то в результате есть объект **DateInterval** от которой тоже надо отнимать время, как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Преобразуй оба значения в метку времени Unix, отними и преобразуй обратно

```
$date1 = '2018-03-01';
$date2 = '2018-03-02';
$result = strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1);
echo date('Y-m-d', $result);
```